# Installing mailx on ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mailx

So I've installed mailx but I'm unable to get it to send an e-mail. I do the following:

```
mailx -s "Test"
To: myemail@email.com
Cc:
"This is a test."
CTRL-D (does not work)
```

CTRL-D does nothing. It's supposed to end the body and fire off the e-mail, but does not seem to be doing anything.

Here's my /etc/hosts file. I'm not sure if this is correct.

```
127.0.0.1      localhost localhost. hp-laptop hp-laptop.
10.XXX.X.XXX   hp-laptop.
```

Any suggestions on what's causing the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you in fact _typing the string_ "CTRL-D", or are you pressing `Ctrl` and `d` together (which is what you should be doing). I believe typing a lone dot on a line also ends the message.

Answer (score 0):

Change `/etc/hosts` to this:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost localhost. hp-laptop hp-laptop. vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
10.XXX.X.XXX   hp-laptop.
```

When the smtp connection to Gmail times out, you misconfigured the smtp server data in your MTA configuration (like sendmail, exim or postfix). Be aware that the gmail smtp server to not support smtp connections to port 25 and without encryption.

Comment: So that allowed the CTRL-D to work, but I never received an e-mail.

Comment: My mailq has the below messages in it.

Comment: `MTA Queue status...
                /var/spool/mqueue (8 requests)
                                                 -----Q-ID----- --Size-- -----Q-Time----- ------------Sender/Recipient------    -----
t6MH143q002470*      11 Wed Jul 22 17:01 <root@localhost>
                                         <myemail@gmail.com>
t6MGUFWa002231*       5 Wed Jul 22 16:30 <vagrant@localhost>
                 (Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.goo)
                                         <myemail@gmail.com>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happenned when you tried it before but changing your hosts file would not change the behaviour of ctrl-d.

If your mail is in the local queue then mailx has done it's job - but you've not configured your MTA properly or there is an issue with the network config. Unless you really know what you're doing you will find it a lot easier to use a SMTP service than running your own MTA. While some MUAs (e.g. mutt) can connect directly to an external MTA over SMTP with authentication (e.g. mutt) you could use [nullmailer with gmail](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Nullmailer).